# Leaflet exporting using toGeoJSON does not automatically add properties for things like color, name, description, etc

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a project that utilizes Leaflet with a lot of tailored markers and colored lines/polygons. We are not using a GeoJSON layer in Leaflet.

I would like to export all or a subset of these objects/layers to GeoJSON and then import them back in without losing any detail like color and description.

Using the native toGeoJSON function of Leaflet, I can get GeoJSON data for anything I want on the map. Here is some code that produces GeoJSON for everything on the map:

```js
function exportToGeoJSON() {
    var allMarkersObjArray = [];
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        allMarkersObjArray.push(layer); 
    });
    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup(allMarkersObjArray);
    var data = layerGroup.toGeoJSON(); 
    var json = JSON.stringify(data); // Stringify the object
    return json;
}
```

A snippet of the resulting GeoJSON created looks like this:

```js
{
"type":"Feature",
"properties":{},
"geometry":{
"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-75.668159,36.014897]}
}
```

We get the basic geometry which is nice but no properties with things like:

```
  "properties": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": “Marker 1”,
      "description": “This is a marker”,
      "marker-size": "small",
      "marker-color": "#f5a91a",
      "marker-symbol": "b"
  }
```

I want to find the best way to create these properties. I could certainly build the code to extract the properties from the Leaflet Marker object as an example but maybe there is a better way.

I have searched for potential plug-ins to do this but nothing is coming up on the radar screen. I would think other folks would like this type of capability.

Anyway, any thought or comments are welcome.